# How to register Yii's autoloader in an external application?

Tags: php, yii, autoload, autoloader, spl-autoload-register

I want to try Yii, but I don't want use it as my main framework. In other words, I want to use my own framework while also using some of Yii's features. I figured that in order to be able to instantiate Yii's classes from my application, I'd just need to register Yii's autoloader from my application, probably in a way similar to this:

```
spl_autoload_register
(
    function ($classname)
    {
        YiiBase::autoload($className);
    }
);
```

Of course, I'm gonna need to require or include the YiiBase class, so before I call the previous function, I do this:

```
$yiiBase = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/yii/framework/YiiBase.php';
require_once($yiiBase);
```

But I get a "Cannot redeclare class YiiBase" error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Do not include YiiBase.php direcly, include yii.php. Because yii.php contains a class `Yii` which is used in all over framework code (even in YiiBase methods).

```
 $yii = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/yii/framework/yii.php';
 require_once($yii);
```

( and YiiBase.php is included in yii.php by default)

2) register your `autoload handler` in this way.
(Yii has built-in functionality to add custom autoload handlers ).

```
$my_autoload =  function($class) { ... };
// OR
// $my_autoload = array('MyClass', 'my_autoload')

YiiBase::registerAutoloader($my_autoload, true);
```

The second parameter `true` tells `whether to append/prepend the new autoloader after/before the default Yii autoloader`

*if the YiiBase.php included, then Yii's default autoloader will also gets included. No need to call `YiiBase::autoload()` explicitly in you code. **Ref**:  check the last line in YiiBase.php file*

Comment: It worked, thanks! I don't need YiiBase::registerAutoloader($my_autoload, true) though. It actually gives me the "Cannot redeclare class YiiBase" if I add that.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at some approaches of people [integrating Yii with wordpress](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/?tag=wordpress), you may not need to do ->run() the application, unless you need the controllers/routing, it also depends on what parts of the framework you pretend to use.

Answer (score 0):

To do it for Yii2, [this article](https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tutorial-yii-integration/) explains it under the heading "*Using Yii in Third-Party Systems*" in the middle of the page.

Here is the relevant part to include on startup of your external application:

```php
  require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
  $yiiConfig = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/yii/web.php');
  new yii\web\Application($yiiConfig); // Do NOT call run() here
```

Obviously, `__DIR__ . '/../` may need to be adjusted to fit your directory layout.